# MySQL writing efficient procedures for geometry queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is a question regarding efficiency because what I want to write is likely to break my machine.

Brief description. I have two sets of data,

Set1 contains ~2500 entries, each entry has a polygon associated.

Set2 contains ~4000 entries, each entry has a point associated.

I want to find out which polygons from set1 enclose which points from set2. All points and polygons are unique and do not overlap.

I was about to embark on writing a procedure using a nested cursor that will look at a point in set2 scroll through all of set1 and find a polygon that encloses the point.

Then I realized how much data I have, that I will want to run it more than once, and this may take quite a while. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL for Geometry - Fine**.

1. Does not seem to be a lengthy process.
2. You may or may not have nested cursor.
3. You can pretty well create a linked **view** having each point from **set2** along with **all poygons enclosing** the point.
4. And that **view** can be called from your code for selection list, etc (replacing your expected cursor). Once the view is defined, MySQL will be almost ready with the output always.